# C# Could not find the data provider. NET Framework requested

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, system.data.sqlite

Im using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, C# WPF, MVVM, Sqlite.

I have this project that is running without problems (On Windows 8 x64, .NET Framework 4 Client Proile), but I get all this exceptions when run an installed application (On Windows 7 x32, .NET Framework 4 Client Proile):

```
Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor of type' GestorDocument.UI.DeterminanteView 'that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' (Line number: '3 ', line position '9'). ---> System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider can not be found in the configuration or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not find the data provider. NET Framework requested. It may not be installed.
```

This is my connection string:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="GestorDocumentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GestorDocument.csdl|res://*/GestorDocument.ssdl|res://*/GestorDocument.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\SQLITE\BD\GestorDocument.s3db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>  
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup></configuration>
```

Please, Any idea?

---

**Now it works!
MY SOLUTION WAS:**

App.config in your project:

```
    <configuration>  

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.85.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>


      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Include a reference of: (version for the machine on which the application will be installed.)

- SQLite.Designer.dll
- System.Data.SQLite.dll
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll

Set "Copy local" property to True.

Add in machine.config this line between system.data and DbProviderFactories

```
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.85.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
```

Ensure that the version of. NET Framework, which was developed the application, is installed on the test machine.

Comment: Is the project set to run any cpu or 32 bit / 64 bit only?  If you change to 32 bit on your dev machine - do you get the same errors?  Do you get the errors on the windows 7 machine if explicitly set for 32 bit?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I've been testing changed to "Any CP" or "x86" or "x64" and I get the same errors.

Answer (score 3):

The `System.Data.SQLite` provider isn't installed on the machine.  The correct installation not only drops the binaries on the machine (probably the GAC), but also drops an entry into machine.config that looks something like this (this is NOT REAL):

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="System.Data.SQLite"
         invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
         description="SQLite Framework Data Provider for SQLite databases lol"
         type="SomeProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Etcetera=etcetera"/>
    <!--snip-->
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Configuration settings (like this database provider configuration) in **machine.config** are inherited by your application's `derp.exe.config` file.  In your .config file, you are configuring EF to use the SQLite provider (from the middle of your EF connection string):

```
provider=System.Data.SQLite;
```

If you look up at the hypothetical entry, it has a provider name that's the same as in your connection string.  That's how EF knows to use the SQLite factory to create a connection to the database.  See, it's not really magic at all.  Its just hidden.

So what's the solution?  Hell if I know.  I mean, I use a REAL compact database, not this SQLite stuff.  You will either have to install SQLite on the target machine, add the factory definition to your .config file, or do something else, like construct a plane out of bamboo.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am beginner in c#. But I installed the System.Data.SQLite in both machines. Could be something else?

Comment: @DianeWaldorf: Probably not.  Have you confirmed that the provider is defined on the machine where the error is happening?

Comment: What do you mean with :is defined"?

Comment: @DianeWaldorf: Open machine.config for the version of .net you are targeting on the machine you are having this issue.  Search for "sqlite".  If you don't find it, my answer is correct. You will either have to reinstall, or copy the entry from your development machine and put it in your .config file or in the target machine's machine.config.  Can't be much simpler than that.

Comment: I can open the project in another computer but I have another issue :( When I open it on the machine where I develop works well and loads the main grid information and performs operations should.

But when I install it on another computer, the installer works fine and I can open the application but does not load any information.

Comment: @DianeWaldorf I'd hesitate to say that you must ask a new question, as you don't appear to have one yet.  "It doesn't work, why?" is not an acceptable question here.  You are going to have to start at point zero and check every assumption, from "did the correct files install" to "does the data exist" etc etc.  Nobody here can help you with that.

Comment: Did you install the 32 bit driver for the Win7 machine?

Comment: @Geek Thanks for answering, 32 bit driver for what? Sqlite?

Comment: @geek lol, teach me something I don't know.  But there is always a limit to answers you can get from an online help site.  When you don't know how the magic works... well, you're getting near the end of the rope.  The whole problem here is getting sqlite working on a target box.  If you have problems understanding that, then you are in a pickle that only an experienced developer can help you with.  Unless you can break problems down to their most basic components.  But you have to actively do such.  It takes time and effort.

Comment: "it doesn't load any information" isn't a problem anyone online can solve for you.  You have to debug, create prototypes, add in extra tracing code, etc.  We have all been in there, but unless you're lucky and this is something obvious (and in this case, as one who has had similar issues getting data providers working, everything up until the "it doesn't work" point is obvious), you have to work towards a solution yourself.  I guess the real answer is "one of your assumptions is incorrect", but who knows?  Programming is complex and requires complex testing.  :/

Comment: I'd suggest some investigation, and possibly a new question if fruit is found.  Or, you might be able to add some info here.  Of course, that won't help anyone else looking for the same situation, if you two are able to identify what is actually going on here.

Comment: @Geek keep your passive agressivity off me.  If you have a problem take it to [meta].

Comment: Post to this forum was not my first choice. Obviously, I tested, implement methods to know what type of exception was, and research on other pages. Now, I figured it out .. and not only was set machine.config. By the way, I found several questions similar to mine, and no user was as rude as you have been, but .. Thanks for responding. I did not come here trying to make you solve my problem, just looking for some guidance. I'm new to this language, to understand its operation ... but not in programming. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @wpfc  I am glad you solved it.  You will find that most people on here attempt to be helpful.  Your best option is to just ignore the ones that aren't - since they normally can't change as they don't realize part of the problem lies with them.  Good luck to you.

Comment: @wpfc: (btw I didn't downvote your question) Trust me, it doesn't matter to me if you don't upvote (or downvote) or don't select my answer as correct.  But  it is important to upvote answers that helped you, and select answers as correct when they do the most to help solve your problem.  If you expect answers which provide you 100% of a solution, you will not be happy.  The best anyone can hope for is answers which guide you to a solution that would have taken you exponentially longer to find on your own.